# Minimum coin change class giving wrong answer

Tags: python, algorithm, coin-change

Trying to [solve] the problem in leetcode (322):

> You are given coins of different denominations and a total amount of
>   money amount. Write a function to compute the fewest number of coins
>   that you need to make up that amount. If that amount of money cannot
>   be made up by any combination of the coins, return -1.

I am stuck in this input: coins = [2] and target = 3

I wonder why it is returning 0? I debugged this but not able to figure out.

```
class Solution(object):
    def coinChange(self, coins, amount):
        """
        :type coins: List[int]
        :type amount: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        def get_cost(coins, amount):
            if amount == 0:
                return 0
            min_cost = float('inf')
            for coin in coins:
                if amount >= coin:
                    min_cost = min(min_cost, 1 + self.coinChange(coins, amount - coin))
            return min_cost

        cost = get_cost(coins, amount)
        if cost == float('inf'):
            return -1
        return cost
```

Comment: Tag all change-making questions [tag:coin-change]. That way you can find related questions.

Comment: Its returning -1, tested in https://ideone.com/Q0izhw

Comment: @AnupamGhosh: Try it here https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/description/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is not correct, you want to do something like this: the minimum cost either contains the current coin or it does not. This would in pseudo code look like:

```
min_coins = current cost + min(cost without using this coin, cost using this coin)
```

so you should put the current cost in your state and also keep track of which coins you are allowed to use.